# Can a fighter with the Great Weapon Fighting fighting style reroll his damage many times?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage, fighter, fighting-style

A situation arose yesterday wherein a player with a fighter that had the Great Weapon Fighting fighting style rolled a '1' on his damage. He re-rolled and got a '2'. He re-rolled AGAIN and got a '4'.

That seemed odd to me, so we checked in the book and it said nothing about only re-rolling once. Not wanting to slow the game, I voiced my concern and let it slide (they were in a thug-fight so it did not matter in the grand scheme of things).

Then this morning I wondered it we had an old copy of the book or what we missed. Is there a rule somewhere that states where you can only reroll once?

Comment: Can you quote the wording in the book you have, if it's different from the answer?  Or was this just a case of not seeing a phrase that's obvious only in hindsight?

Comment: @PeterCordes It was the player's own book, not mine. I don't have access to it for a few weeks. :(

Comment: Related: [Which damage dice exactly does the Great Weapon Fighting fighting style allow you to reroll?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/94046/which-damage-dice-exactly-does-the-great-weapon-fighting-fighting-style-allow-yo)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

### The fighter can reroll (at most) once.

The [Great Weapon Fighting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#FightingStyle-191) style says the following (emphasis added by me):

> When you roll a 1 or 2 on a damage die for an attack you make with a melee weapon that you are wielding with two hands, you can reroll the die and **must use the new roll, even if the new roll is a 1 or a 2**. The weapon must have the two-handed or versatile property for you to gain this benefit.

They can reroll any damage dice that rolled a 1 or 2, but each individual die can be rerolled only once.

If a rerolled damage die is a 1 or 2, they have to accept it. The fighter doesn't get to reroll it again.

Comment: That's kind of strange. Was this errata'd (as the OP asked about potentially having an old book) or has it always been like that?

Comment: I have a copy of the first printing, and it reads as quoted.

Comment: I have the errata'd pdf version of the PHB, and there is no alteration on this. I would also clarify that this is *per dice*. For example, a Greatsword uses 2d6. If the player rolls a one or a two on both dice, they can re-roll *each* d6 *once*.